# Solve $(x^2-1)^2 (x^2+1)$≡0 mod 81

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to solve the congruence $f(x) \equiv  0$ mod $81$, where $f(x)=(x^2-1)^2(x^2+1) $. In my compendium I have the following theorem[image]

After looking on google I guess it's called Hensel's lemma. My try:

$f(x)=(x^2-1)^2(x^2+1)=x^6-x^4-x^2+1 $ and $f'(x)=6x^5-4x^3-2x $

Since $81=3^4 \hspace{2mm}$  I can start by looking at $$(x^2-1)^2(x^2+1)\equiv 0 \hspace{1.5mm}mod\hspace{1.5mm}3$$

then $a=1$ & $a=2$ are solutions

$f(1)=0 $, $\hspace{2mm} f'(1)=0 $, $ \hspace{2mm} f(2)=45 \hspace{2mm} $ &   $\hspace{2mm} f'(2)=156 $

---

So I cant use (i) since $3\mid 0 \hspace{2mm}$ & $\hspace{2mm}3 \mid 156  $

---

For $a=1 \hspace{2mm}$ I can use (ii) since $\hspace{2mm} 3 \mid 0 \hspace{2mm} $ & $\hspace{2mm} 3^2 \mid 0 \hspace{2mm} $ so the solution is  $\hspace{2mm} a+p^kj=1+3j $

---

For $a=2 \hspace{2mm}$ I can't use (ii) since $\hspace{2mm} 3^2 \nmid 156\hspace{2mm} $ so only (iii) is applicable so there are no solutions if $\hspace{2mm}a=2$

So I should use  (ii) with $\hspace{1mm} a=1$ to raise it and continue until I'm at $\hspace{1mm} 3^4 \hspace{1mm} $ or am I completely wrong and misunderstanding the theorem? If so I would really appreciate if someone could shed some clarity on it.

---

I found this [site](http://math453spring2009.wikidot.com/hensel-s-lemma) and following that one only (2) will work just like above with $a=1$, I'll then get:
$$f(4) \equiv 0 mod 9 $$ or $$f(7)\equiv 0 mod 9 $$

However, now I'm kind of stuck on how to raise it to $3^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hensel lifting works. Use base three, so that $9$ is written as $100$, $27$ as $1\,000$, and $81$ as $10\,000$.

The roots modulo $10$ are

$$\begin{array}{rrr}
  1, &2\text{.}
\end{array}$$

For all of these roots, we are in case (ii), so the roots modulo $100$ are

$$\begin{array}{rrr}
  1, &11, &21, \\
  2, &12, &22  \text{.}
\end{array}$$

At this order, only $1$ and $22$ are in case (ii), with the rest in case (iii). Therefore the roots modulo $1000$ are

$$\begin{array}{rrr}
   1, &101, &201, \\
  22, &122, &222  \text{.}
\end{array}$$

All of these roots are in case (ii), so the roots modulo $10\,000$ are

$$\begin{array}{rrr}
  1, &1001, &2001, \\
101, &1101, &2101, \\
201, &1201, &2201, \\
 22, &1022, &2022, \\
122, &1122, &2122, \\
222, &1222, &2222  \text{.}
\end{array}$$

Comment: Do one have to go to base three though? Because I realized that the root 2 is also in case(ii) then I used the lemma and got $f(2+3t) ≡ 0 mod 3^2$ and I found that t=1 so then I get that $f(5) ≡ 0 mod 3^2$ but I'm not sure how to lift it another time.

Comment: or $t=2$ then I get $f(8)\equiv 0 mod 9$ and $f'(8)\equiv 0 mod9$ but again, not sure how to raise it a second time.

Comment: Now I understand it, thanks!